# php doesn't update page until finishing loading

Tags: php, web-crawler

I want to write a crawler script with php and it is necessery to show pages which is indexing online. however, php doesn't update page real time, sometimes it write a few echos together and wait until finishing loading, sometimes nothing seems in page until finishing loading.

Here is an example about what I'm talking:

```
<?php
echo '1<br>';
sleep(2);
echo '2<br>';
sleep(2);
echo '3<br>';
sleep(2);
echo '4<br>';
?>
```

I tried on wamp and lamp and results were same. is there any way to show echos real time?

note: I found [an online crawler which has this feature](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/crawlproc.html?&initurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com&freq&lastmod=1&lastmodtime=2011-05-07+12%3A37%3A59&priority=none&submit=Start).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [`flush()`](http://se.php.net/flush).

Another, more manual, way is to query the server multiple times via ajax or using something like [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29).

Comment: thanks @chelmertz, this is awesome. I found something which is exactly I want: http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php#58917

Comment: @Burak Emre: Cool, I've never seen that before. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use some JavaScript to self refresh the page and it can then be called after each routine to run the necessary php function.

Comment: yes, I know but this is an useless way to do this, because I have to save results for each url.

Comment: Let me reiterate my statement, use javascript to refresh the page and call a different php page which does the job of saving the result for each URL..

Comment: I mean it can cause cpu overloading, and the other way which is using php's functions to fix this problem is faster than using javascript. If I create a sitemap.xml file, the best way is write the file when operation finished.
If you mean my english is wrong, I accept it. :)